# Weather Underground Hourly 1-day Forecast

Tags: jquery, json

I am taking the Weather Underground API, using json and parsing variables. I have an issue. I cannot figure out how to display the hourly 1-day forecast like something like so:

Hourly Forecast 11AM EST on January 25, 2015

60F 55F Mostly Cloudy

16 MPH NNW 41

60F

This will explain more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6A138NBuyk&feature=youtu.be at 3:30 time.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/72df18b7f213607b/hourly/q/CO/Alamosa.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        var hourly = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['FCTTIME'];


        for(index in hourly)
            var newHourly = 'Today is' + hourly_forecast[index]['weekday_name'];
            $(".hourFore").append(newHourly);
    }

});
```

Here is the weather underground api doc for hourly: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/hourly&MR=1

Answer (score 1):

`hourly_forecast` is an array of objects that contain `FCTTIME` in each.

I'm not going to try and parse all the various components of it for you but you can see the general approach to accessing it here:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wunderground.com/api/72df18b7f213607b/hourly/q/CO/Alamosa.json',function(resp){
    $.each(resp.hourly_forecast, function(){
        logTime(this.FCTTIME);        
    });

});

function logTime( obj){
    $('body').append(obj.weekday_name + ' '+  obj.civil +'<br>');
    console.log(obj);
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yjg1mwwd/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks. However I think the hourly day is supposed to show the day of and the hour in real-time. What you did gives an array of every day and every hour.

Comment: I was showing you how to access the data that you were having problems getting to based on the url you provided. Up to you to put together what you need. Can inspect the data in browser console and do what ever parsing you want with it

Comment: What function would I use beside .each to only get the day of an not every day of the week? It seems like .each does a foreach.

Comment: depends on what data you want. I don't plan to read the API docs or spend a lot of time analyzing the returned data ...there's a lot of it in that one call. Inspect it in your browser console